# Groovy: Multiple assignments not allowed in fields

Tags: class, variables, gradle, groovy, multiple-assignment

When I tried to declare my variables using multiple assignment, it came up with the error

> Multiple assignments not allowed in fields

```
    class Ana {
        def tmp = []
        String subject
        def (ini, sorted, full) = ['','',[:]]

    Ana(subject) {
        this.subject = subject
    }
}
```

However, it shows no error when I declare them one by one.

Wondering why this is the case

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9UmR.png)

Comment: why would you want to do it?

Comment: @injecteer just wondering why it isn't allowed

Comment: I don't really know why groovy does not allows this, but there are many reasons not to do it from the general point of view.